# Clicking on `<select>` causes the page to move unnecessarily

Tags: html, svelte

Steps:

- open this REPL in Chrome (no problem in Firefox) -
  https://svelte.dev/repl/b739483ffedc4e33bc4f6f2626c013ff?version=3.47.0

```html
  <div style="display: flex; align-items: flex-start;">
      <!-- svelte-ignore a11y-autofocus -->
      <select style="position: sticky; top: 10px;">
          <option>he1</option>
          <option>he2</option>
          <option>he3</option>
          <option>he4</option>
      </select>
      
      <div style="height: 1000px;"></div>
  </div>
```

- scroll down the page
- click on `<select>`
- the page will scroll to the top by itself

[image]

As it should be: The page should not scroll at all.

Comment: Questions should be self contained. A link to a REPL is nice, but the code should be in the question as well.

Comment: Cannot reproduce this at all, tried Chrome, FF and Edge. The browser should detect that the element is in view and not scroll.

Comment: @HB Chrome 100.0.4896.127, Arch Linux.

Comment: @H.B.  I added a gif. You have to manually deselect `<select>` and then click - it will then scroll.

Comment: Possibly a Linux-only issue then and something that should be reported as a Chromium bug.

Comment: I reported via "Menu -> Help -> Report an issue".

Answer (score 2):

It's weird, but it works:It's weird, but it works:
https://svelte.dev/repl/3c59bf53bf2a4f7b841edc03c6e1839d?version=3.47.0

```html
<div style="display: flex; align-items: flex-start;">
    <!-- svelte-ignore a11y-autofocus -->
    <select style="position: sticky; top: 10px;"
        on:mousedown={ e=> e.target.focus({ preventScroll: true }) }
    >
        <option>he1</option>
        <option>he2</option>
        <option>he3</option>
        <option>he4</option>
    </select>
    
    <div style="height: 1000px;"></div>
</div>
```

This: `on:mousedown={ e=> e.target.focus({ preventScroll: true }) }`

If you have something better, please provide.